# How to write a text file with color

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a text file with two colors depending on the output. I using the `echo -e` command as I would when printing with colors in the console, like this:

```
RETURNED=$?
if [ $RETURNED == 0 ]
   then
      echo -e "\e[1;32mffmpeg -t $DURACION -f x11grab -s $RESOLUCION -r ${FPS[j]} -b:v $BR -i :0.0 -y $NOMBRE\e[0m" >> file.txt

fi
```

The idea would be: If the command worked, then write a green line, else use red. However I'm not getting any colored line in the text file.

Comment: How are you displaying the file?

Comment: When I run just the echo I see the text green. Even when I redirect the echo to a file like you and I cat the file I still see the text green.

Comment: Does the word-processor in which you open the file support coloured text ?

Comment: ohh...can you first try to color up line in your notepad or word processor?

Comment: Colors are interpreted by your terminal, so try a different terminal, check your terminal settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried `less -R file.txt`? That should show you the colour (works for me at least).

If you want colour coding which is supported by non-shell applications your best bet is probably to output HTML, for example:

```
printf '<code style="color: %s;">%s</code>' "green" "ffmpeg -t $DURACION -f x11grab -s $RESOLUCION -r ${FPS[j]} -b:v $BR -i :0.0 -y $NOMBRE" >> file.html
```

Comment: Thanks, was useful at least I can check it. However if I open it with for example Sublime text, it does not works. As jkbkot said colors are interpreted by the terminal, so is there another command allows me to write the textile with color?

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` instead of `echo -e`:

`printf` *portably* supports interpreting `\`-based escape sequences, whereas `echo -e` isn't supported on all platforms, notably not on macOS.

```
printf "\e[1;32mffmpeg -t $DURACION -f x11grab -s $RESOLUCION -r ${FPS[j]}\
-b:v $BR -i :0.0 -y $NOMBRE\e[0m\n" >> file.txt
```

Note the trailing `\n` to print a newline after the string, because `printf` - unlike `echo` - doesn't automatically add one.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer.  Use printf instead of echo.  And as I0b0 says, less requires -R to display colors.  printf replaced the string "\e" with the single byte \x1b